Fourth order BVP partial differential equation
I am trying to solve fourth order partial differential equation describing a fluid problem, by using Mathematica. The PDE is provided here as:
$(1/4)f_{yyt} + H^4(ff_{yyy} - f_y f_{yy})=1/{H^2R(yf_{yyyy + 2f_{yyy}})}$
Along with the boundary conditions:
$f(0,t)=0,$ $f(1,t)=0,$ $f_y(1,t)=-\dot{H}/2H^5$
$\lim_{y\to0}\{y^{1/2}f_y(1,t)\}=0$
Where,
$H=1+\Delta \cos(2t)$    and $\dot{H}$   is the derivative of $H$ with respect to $t$.
My working for the given problem is:
H[t_] := 1 + \[CapitalDelta] *Cos[2* t];
R = 1;
H1 := D[H[t], t];
NDSolve[{(1/4)*(Derivative[2, 1][f][y,t]) + (H^4)*(f[y, t]*Derivative[3, 0][f][y,t] - (Derivative[1, 0][f][y, t])*(Derivative[2, 0][f][y,t])) == (1/R*H^2)*(y*(Derivative[4, 0][f][y, t]) + 2*(Derivative[3, 0][f][y, t])), f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][f][1, t] == -H1/(2*H^5), Limit[Sqrt[y]*(Derivative[2, 0][f][1, t]) == 0, y -> 0] ==0}, f, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0,1}]

Range for $\Delta$ is: $0 < \Delta < 1$
The output for this problem is also provided here:
NDSolve::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.

The Manuscript is also provided here:
https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112003003835
The above stated PDE is on page number $208$ of the given manuscript against the equation number $(5.1)$ along with boundary conditions $(5.2a)$ and $(5.2b)$.
If you need more information or think I missed something, please let me know.

Could you give title of paper instead of link?

It is not clear from the paper Blyth, M. G., Hall, P., & Papageorgiou, D. T. (2003). Chaotic flows in pulsating cylindrical tubes: A class of exact Navier-Stokes solutions. Journal of Fluid Mechanics, (481), 187-213. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112003003835 what is initial condition for this equation, so we can put $f(y,0)=0$ and use implicit step to solve this equation as follows
soln[delta_] := 
 Module[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta, dt = 1/50, nmax = 50, 
   y0 = $MachineEpsilon}, H[t_] := 1 + \[CapitalDelta]*Cos[2*t];
  R = 1;
  dH[t_] := -2 \[CapitalDelta]*Sin[2*t]; G[0][y_] := 0; F[0][y] := 0;
  Do[{F[i], G[i]} = 
     NDSolveValue[{g[y] == 
        f''[y], (1/4)*(g[y] - G[i - 1][y])/dt + 
         H[i  dt]^4 (F[i - 1][y] g'[y] - f'[y] G[i - 1][y]) == (1/(R H[i  dt]^2))*(y*g''[y] + 2*g'[y]), f[y0] == 0, f[1] == 0, 
       f'[1] == -dH[i  dt]/(2*H[i  dt]^5), g[y0] == 0}, {f, g}, {y, 
       y0, 1}];, {i, nmax}]; Table[F[i][y], {i, nmax}]]

Example of usage
sol05 = soln[.5];

Visualization f[y,t] at different t
pl=Plot[Evaluate@Table[sol05[[i]], {i, 5, 50, 5}], {y, 0, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"y", "f"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t = ", i /50.}], {i, 5, 50, 5}]] 


Visualization f[y,t] at different y
ListLinePlot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[Transpose[{Range[1/50, 1, 1/50], 
     sol05}], {y, {.1, .25, .5, .75, .9}}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "f"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"y = ", y}], {y, {.1, .25, .5, .75, .9}}], 
 PlotRange -> All]


Update 1. FDM solution
Attributes[MakeVariables] = {Listable};
MakeVariables[var_, n_] := Table[Unique[var], {n}]

soln[delta_] := 
 Module[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta, dt = 1/50, nmax = 50, dy = 1/10}, 
  H[t_] := 1 + \[CapitalDelta]*Cos[2*t];
  R = 1;
  dH[t_] := -2 \[CapitalDelta]*Sin[2*t]; ygrid = Range[0, 1, dy]; 
  ny = Length[ygrid]; 
  dy2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], ygrid, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; 
  dy1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ygrid, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; {fvar1, gvar1} = 
   MakeVariables[{ff, gg}, ny]; fvar0 = ConstantArray[0, {ny, nmax}]; 
  gvar0 = ConstantArray[0, {ny, nmax}];
  Do[{fvar, gvar} = {fvar0[[All, i]], gvar0[[All, i]]}; 
   eqf = gvar1 - dy2 . fvar1; 
   eqg = (1/4)*(gvar1 - gvar)/dt + 
     H[(i + 1)  dt]^4 (fvar  (dy1 . gvar1) - (dy1 . 
           fvar1)  gvar) - (1/(R*
        H[(i + 1)  dt]^2))*(ygrid  (dy2 . gvar1) + 2  dy1 . gvar1); 
   eqf[[1]] = fvar1[[1]]; eqf[[-1]] = fvar1[[-1]];
   eqg[[1]] = gvar1[[1]]; 
   eqg[[-1]] = (dy1 . fvar1)[[-1]] + 
     dH[(i + 1)  dt]/(2*H[(i + 1)  dt]^5);
   eqns = Join[eqf, eqg]; 
   var = Join[fvar1, gvar1]; {vec, mat} = 
    CoefficientArrays[eqns, var]; 
   sol = LinearSolve[mat, -vec]; {fvar0[[All, i + 1]], 
     gvar0[[All, i + 1]]} = Partition[sol, Length[ygrid]];, {i, 
    nmax - 1}]; {fvar0, gvar0}]

Example of usage
sol05 = soln[.5]; // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 0.08s on my laptop. Visualization
pl1 = ListLinePlot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[Transpose[{ygrid, sol05[[1]][[All, i]]}], {i, 5, 50, 5}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"y", "f"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t = ", i /50.}], {i, 5, 50, 5}]]


Since last code is very fast, we can make parametric research as follows
delta0 = Range[.1, 1, .1]; sol1 = soln[#] & /@ delta0;

Visualization f[y,t] at t=1 and for different $\Delta$
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Transpose[{ygrid, sol1[[i, 1]][[All, -1]]}], {i, 
   Length[delta0]}], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"y", "f(y,1)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Table[Row[{"\[CapitalDelta] = ", delta0[[i]]}], {i, 
    Length[delta0]}], InterpolationOrder -> 2]


Numerical data for picture above
Table[{delta0[[i]], 
   Transpose[{ygrid // N, sol1[[i, 1]][[All, -1]]}]}, {i, 
   Length[delta0]}] // TableForm

We show data for $\Delta =0.9,1$ only

Update 2. MOL solution based on the debugged code @
Ulrich Neumann
solMOL[delta_] := 
 Module[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta, dy = 1/20, R = 1, diffO = 4}, 
  H = Function[t, 1 + \[CapitalDelta]*Cos[2*t]]; yi = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nmax = Length[yi]; 
  M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  M3 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[3], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  M4 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[4], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  fi = Table[f[i][t], {i, nmax}]; 
  eqn = (1/4 (M2 . D[fi, t]) + 
     H[t]^4 (fi (M3 . fi) - (M1 . fi) (M2 . fi)) - 
     1/(R H[t]^2) (yi  (M4 . fi) + 2 (M3 . fi)));
  eqn[[1]] = fi[[1]]; eqn[[-1]] = fi[[-1]];
  eqn[[-2]] = (M1 . fi)[[-1]] + H'[t]/(2  H[t]^5); 
  eqn[[2]] == (M2 . fi)[[1]];
  ic = Table[f[i][0] == 0, {i, nmax}];
  NDSolveValue[Join[Map[# == 0 &, eqn], ic], 
   Table[f[i], {i, nmax}], {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]]

Example 0f usage
solm05 = solMOL[.5];

Visualization together with FDM data from above
pl2 = ListLinePlot[
  Evaluate[
   Table[Transpose[{yi, Table[solm05[[i]][t], {i, Length[yi]}]}], {t, 
     Range[.1, 1., .1]}]], PlotStyle -> Dashed]
Show[pl1,pl2]



Interessting answer! How is the replacement f[y] f'''[y]-f'[y]f''[y]->F[i - 1][y] g'[y] - f'[y] G[i - 1][y] justified? Thanks!

@UlrichNeumann Do you mean convergence test? Yes, we can check that for dt=1/100 results are not so differ from above. :)

I expected f[y] f'''[y]-f'[y]f''[y]->f[y] g'[y] - f'[y] g[y] not time shifted(?) F[i - 1][y] g'[y] - f'[y] G[i - 1][y]

@UlrichNeumann Do you understand that in a case of converged numerical solution  `F[i - 1][y] g'[y] - f'[y] G[i - 1][y]->f[y] g'[y] - f'[y] g[y] at $dt\rightarrow 0$?

Thanks, that's understood. That is the main idea of the method used?

@UlrichNeumann Yes, this is implicit solver of order $dt^2$, so we don't need to compute nonlinear terms as it is, but we can use linear form as in my code.  Please note, that we can use nonlinear form as well and solve algebraic equations with FindRoot instead of NDSolve.  Also, we can use linear form and solve it with LinearSolve instead of NDSolve.  There are many possibilities to solve this equation with wavelets. And for each method I already have well tested codes. :)

Thanks, very helpful explaination!

Did you try to solve this problem using difference method (NDSolveFiniteDifferenceDerivative[`) and MethodOfLines too?

@Alex thank you for your directions. Could you provide the table of numerical  values for different values of $Delta$ in the given range, i.e., $0<Delta<1$

@UlrichNeumann Please, see Update 1 with FDM solution. :)

@MuhammadZeeshankhan Do you mean table f[y, t] at delta=Range[0,1,0.1], and for example,  at t=1, y=0.5?

@AlexTrounev yes.

@AlexTrounev Thanks for your update! What I meant is the solution of the nonlinear system, see my extended comment&code which doesn't evaluate. Perhaps you might see why?

@MuhammadZeeshankhan Please, see Update 1 with pictures and data.

After discussing all these interesting variants provided by @AlexTrounev here my approach using MethodOfLines with TensorProductGrid which possibly answers QP's initial question.
F[\[CapitalDelta]_] := 
 Module[{H = Function[t, 1 + \[CapitalDelta]*Cos[2*t]],
   R = 1}  , 
  NDSolveValue[{(1/4)*(Derivative[2, 1][f][y, 
         t]) + (H[t]^4)*(f[y, t]*
          Derivative[3, 0][f][y, 
           t] - (Derivative[1, 0][f][y, t])*(Derivative[2, 0][f][y, 
            t])) == 
     1/(R*H[t]^2)*(y*(Derivative[4, 0][f][y, t]) + 
        2*(Derivative[3, 0][f][y, t])), f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0][f][1, t] == -H'[t]/(2*H[t]^5), f[y, 0] == 0
    , Derivative[2, 0][f][1, t] == 0 }, f, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]
  
  ]

Plot3D[Evaluate[F[1/2][y, t]], {t, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,MeshFunctions -> (#1 &) , AxesLabel -> {t, y , f[y, t]}]



extended comment
Here my approach to solve the nonlinear problem using FDM & MethodOfLines.
solU =.
solU[delta_] := 
 Module[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta, dy = 1/50 , nmax = 50 , 
   yi = Subdivide[0, 1, 50 ] , R = 1, diffO = 4} ,
  H   = Function[t, 1 + \[CapitalDelta]*Cos[2*t ]]; (* H[t]*)
      
  M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  M3 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[3], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  M4 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[4], yi, 
     DifferenceOrder -> diffO]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  
  fi = Table[f[i][t], {i, 0, nmax}];(* Diskretisierung f[y ] *)
  eqn = (1/4 M2 . D[fi, t] + H[t]^4 (fi M3 . fi - M1 . fi M2 . fi) - 
     R/H[t]^2 (yi M4 . fi + M3 . fi))   ;
  eqn[[1]] = f'[0][t]; eqn[[-1]] = f'[nmax][t]; 
  eqn[[-2]] = D[(M1 . fi)[[-1]] + H'[t]/(2  H[t]^5) , t];
  (*
  icbc = Join[{ f [0][0] == 0, f [nmax][0] == 0, 
     0 == ( (M1 . fi)[[-1]] + H'[t]/(2  H[t]^5)) /. t -> 0  }, 
    Table[f [i][0] == 0, {i, 1, nmax - 1 }]]  ;
  *)
  icbc = Table[f [i][0] == 0, {i, 0, nmax  }];
    
    NDSolveValue[Join[Map[#\[Equal]0&,eqn],icbc ], Table[f[i] ,{i,0,
  nmax}] ,{t,0,1} ,
  Method\[Rule]{"EquationSimplification"\[Rule]"Residual"} ] 
    ]

Evaluating solU[.5] fails and gives message NDSolveValue::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {f[0][t],f[1][t],f[2][t],f[3][t],f[4][t],f[5][t],f[6][t],f[7][t],f[8][t],f[9][t],<<43>>}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.
I checked Length of eqn (51),  Length of icbc (51), Length of variables Table[f[i] ,{i,0,nmax}] (51).
Any idea what's wrong here? Thanks!

It looks like question in question:)

@AlexTrounev Do you suggest asking a new question?

I have an answer, but I see there is a typo in the equation compared to paper sited. This typo persists in Latex code, in Mathematica code, in your code and in my code as well :(.  It should be $1/(H^2 R) $, while you used R/H^2, in my code typo is same as in OP code (1/R H^2). I should recompute all my pictures.

Please, see Update 2 in my answer.

@AlexTrounev Thank you, the missing boundary condition was the key to the solution. Why is this constraint not needed in your solutions?

In the paper they used constraint $\sqrt{y} f_{yy}(y,t)\rightarrow 0$ at $y\rightarrow 0$ for analytical solution only while for numerical solution this constraint is useless. But if we analyze how they derive equation for f from equations (2.4) we can conclude that $f_{yy}(0,t)=0$ is a good boundary condition that is in agreement with boundary conditions (2.5) in the paper.
