How to solve numerically a fourth order BVP having a Boundary condition at Limit Approaches to 0
I have the following fourth order BVP (pde):
$\frac{1}{4}f_{yyt}+H^{4}(ff_{yyy}-f_{y}f_{yy})=\frac{1}{H^{2}R}(yf_{yyy}+2f_{yy})$
with boundary conditions:
$f(0,t)=0$, $f(1,t)=0$, $f_{y}(1,t)=-\frac{\dot{H}}{2H^{5}}$ and $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\{y^{\frac{1}{2}}f_{y}(1,t)\}=0$,
where
$H=1+\Delta\cos(2t)$ and $\dot{H}$ is the derivative of $H$ wrt to $t$.
Ordinary NDSolve commond fails to solve it, which is given as:
H[t_] := 1 + \[CapitalDelta] *Cos[2* t];
R = 1;
H1 := D[H[t], t];
NDSolve[{(1/4)*(Derivative[2, 1][f][y,t]) + (H^4)*(f[y, t]*Derivative[3, 0][f][y,t] -(Derivative[1, 0][f][y, t])*(Derivative[2, 0][f][y,t])) == (1/R*H^2)*(y*(Derivative[4, 0][f][y,t])+ 2*(Derivative[3, 0][f][y, t])), f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][f][1, t] == H1/(2*H^5), Limit[Sqrt[y]*(Derivative[2, 0][f][1, t]) == 0, y -> 0] ==0}, f, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0,1}]

where $0<\Delta<1$. This equation appeared in the paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231787232_Chaotic_flows_in_pulsating_cylindrical_tubes_A_class_of_exact_Navier-Stokes_solutions
This problem is recently answered in Fourth order BVP partial differential equation but only graphs are obtained.
Infact, I'm now interested to solve it numerically (for $\Delta=0.1$,$\Delta=0.5$ and $\Delta=0.9$) using any numerical method like Homogony analysis method or variational iteration method or Green's function based fixed point method or any other method. But im beginner for pdes. How can I start.

Do you mean to compute some kind of analytical solution using homotopy method?

The limit condition is unclear: Limit[Sqrt[y] Derivative[1][f][1],y->0] is fullfilled because Derivative[1][f][1]==H'[t]/(2 H[t]^5) doesn't depend on y

@Alex yes I'm actually interested in both analytical and numerical solution.

@UlrichNeumann Please note in the paper they used Limit[Sqrt[y] Derivative[2][f][y,t],y->0]

@AlexTrounev That makes more sense, thanks !

@UlrichNeumann Actually we can use more simple condition $f_{yy}(0, t)=0$ that in agreement with general model described in the paper.

@JunaidAhmad Look at my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/306249/fourth-order-bvp-partial-differential-equation. There are 3 methods of numerical solution.
