Solving a Coupled System of Partial Differential Equations with Initial and Boundary Conditions
I am working to solve the provided system containing one PDE coupled with an ODE.
$G_t - \frac{\dot H}{H}\eta G_\eta -\frac{1}{H}FG_\eta +\frac{1}{H}F_\eta G + \frac{2FG}{\eta H}=\frac{1}{H^2R}[G_{\eta\eta} + \frac{1}{\eta}G_\eta - \frac{G}{\eta^2}] $
$F_{\eta\eta} + \frac{1}{\eta}F_\eta - \frac{1}{\eta^2}F=- H^2G$
Along with initial and boundary conditions:
$F(\eta,0)=0, G(\eta,0)=0,  F(0,t)=0, G(0,t)=0$
$F(1,t)=-\dot H,F_\eta(1,t)=\dot H$
Here $\dot H$ is the derivative of $H$ with respect to $t$, where $H=1+\Delta \cos(2t)$, and the parameter $\Delta$ is the oscillation amplitude in the range $0<\Delta <1$.
The above stated system is present in the research article titled as: "Chaotic flows in pulsating cylindrical tubes: a class of exact Navier-Stokes  solutions". Here is the link of the stated research article: https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112003003835
The given system of equations are present on $Page. No:190$ of the article having equation numbers $(2.4a),(2.4b),(2.5a) and (2.5b)$
The solution for $R<<1$ of the given problem, provided in the article is of the form:
$F=\dot H\eta(\eta^2 -2) + O(R)$
$G=-8\eta\dot H/H^2+O(R)$.
Here is my approach to this problem:
ClearAll[G, F, \[CapitalDelta] , H, R, t, \[Eta]]
G[\[Eta]_, t_] = G[\[Eta], t];
F = F[\[Eta], t];
H[t_] := 1 + \[CapitalDelta] *Cos[2* t];
R = 1;
Hdot[t_] := D[H[t], t];


eq1 = D[G, t] - (Hdot[t]/H[t]) *\[Eta] *D[G, \[Eta]] - (1/H[t]) *F *
     D[G, \[Eta]] + (1/H[t]) *D[F, \[Eta]] *
     G + (2 *F* G)/(\[Eta] *H[t]) == (1/(H[t]^2 *R)) *(D[
       G, {\[Eta], 2}] + (1/\[Eta])* D[G, \[Eta]] - G/\[Eta]^2);

eq2 = D[F, {\[Eta], 2}] + (1/\[Eta]) *D[F, \[Eta]] - 
    F/\[Eta]^2 == -H[t]^2 *G;

Define the boundary conditions
bc1 = F[0, t] == 0;
bc3 = F[1, t] == -Hdot[t];
bc4 = (D[F, \[Eta]] /. \[Eta] -> 1) == Hdot[t];
bc2 = G[0, t] == 0;

ic1 = F[\[Eta], 0] == 0;
ic2 = G[\[Eta], 0] == 0;

conditions = {eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, bc5, bc6, ic1, ic2};


solution = NDSolve[conditions, {G, F}, {\[Eta], 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}];


Plot[Evaluate[G[\[Eta], t] /. solution], {\[Eta], 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "t", "G"}, PlotLabel -> "Solution for G"]


Plot[Evaluate[F[\[Eta], t] /. solution], {\[Eta], 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "t", "F"}, PlotLabel -> "Solution for F"]

The output given by the mathematica is:
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of G[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of F[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of G[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of F[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of F[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of F[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of F[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of G[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of G[\[Eta],t].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of G[\[Eta],t].

Need to calculate the chaotic results present in the article. Thanks

Why not to use finite difference method they proposed in the paper?

@AlexTrounev could you provide the finite difference code for this problem? Also is it possible to use "DSolve" command for the above system?

We can't solve this system in 2D using NDSolve. See my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/306249/fourth-order-bvp-partial-differential-equation/306252#306252

We can solve this problem using FDM in space and implicit step in time as follows (see also my answer here)
Attributes[MakeVariables] = {Listable};
MakeVariables[var_, n_] := Table[Unique[var], {n}];

soln[delta_] := 
 Module[{\[CapitalDelta] = delta, dt = 1/100, nmax = 100, dy = 1/10}, 
  H[t_] := 1 + \[CapitalDelta]*Cos[2*t];
  R = 1;
  dH[t_] := -2 \[CapitalDelta]*Sin[2*t]; ygrid = Range[0, 1, dy]; 
  ny = Length[ygrid]; 
  dy2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], ygrid, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; 
  dy1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ygrid, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; {fvar1, gvar1} = 
   MakeVariables[{ff, gg}, ny]; fvar0 = ConstantArray[0, {ny, nmax}]; 
  gvar0 = ConstantArray[0, {ny, nmax}];
  Do[{fvar, gvar} = {fvar0[[All, i]], gvar0[[All, i]]}; 
   eqf = dy2 . fvar1 + (dy1 . fvar1)/ygrid - fvar1/ygrid^2 + 
      gvar1  H[(i + 1) dt]^2 // Quiet; 
   eqg = (gvar1 - gvar)/dt - 
      dH[(i + 1) dt]/
        H[(i + 1)  dt] ygrid (dy1 . gvar1) - (dy1 . gvar1) fvar/
        H[(i + 1)  dt] + 1/H[(i + 1)  dt] (dy1 . fvar) gvar1 + 
      2/(ygrid  H[(i + 1)  dt]) fvar  gvar1 - (1/(R*
           H[(i + 1) dt]^2))*( (dy2 . gvar1) + (dy1 . gvar1)/ygrid - 
         gvar1/ygrid^2) // Quiet; eqf[[1]] = fvar1[[1]]; 
   eqf[[-1]] = fvar1[[-1]] + dH[(i + 1) dt];
   eqg[[1]] = gvar1[[1]]; 
   eqg[[-1]] = (dy1 . fvar1)[[-1]] - dH[(i + 1)  dt];
   eqns = Join[eqf, eqg]; 
   var = Join[fvar1, gvar1]; {vec, mat} = 
    CoefficientArrays[eqns, var]; 
   sol = LinearSolve[mat, -vec]; {fvar0[[All, i + 1]], 
     gvar0[[All, i + 1]]} = Partition[sol, Length[ygrid]];, {i, 
    nmax - 1}]; {fvar0, gvar0}]

Example of usage
sol05 = soln[.5]; // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 0.2s on my laptop. Visualization
{pl1 = ListLinePlot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Transpose[{ygrid, sol05[[1]][[All, i]]}], {i, 10, 100, 10}],
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "F"}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t = ", i /100.}], {i, 10, 100, 10}], 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", InterpolationOrder -> 2], 
 pl2 = ListLinePlot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Transpose[{ygrid, sol05[[2]][[All, i]]}], {i, 10, 100, 10}],
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "G"}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"t = ", i /100.}], {i, 10, 100, 10}], 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", InterpolationOrder -> 2]}


Using this code, we can compute data for several $\Delta=0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.$ at $t=1$
delta0 = Range[.1, 1, .1]; sol1 = soln[#] & /@ delta0;

{ListLinePlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ygrid, sol1[[i, 1]][[All, -1]]}], {i, 
    Length[delta0]}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "F(\[Eta],1)"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"\[CapitalDelta] = ", delta0[[i]]}], {i, 
     Length[delta0]}], InterpolationOrder -> 2], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ygrid, sol1[[i, 2]][[All, -1]]}], {i, 
    Length[delta0]}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "G(\[Eta],1)"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"\[CapitalDelta] = ", delta0[[i]]}], {i, 
     Length[delta0]}], InterpolationOrder -> 2]}


